Three-body London equation van der Waals Forces
I am studying Israelachvili's book "Intermolecular and Surface Forces" (https://doi.org/10.1016/C2009-0-21560-1). Chapter 6 discusses Van der Waals forces. To derive the dispersion interaction between two particles, he uses a dipole-induced dipole interaction. He assumes that particle 1 suddenly creates a dipole, which then generates an electric field at molecule 2, inducing a dipole in molecule 2. Exercise 6.2 of the book asks you to calculate the effect of adding a third particle to the interaction. My approach is as follows: molecule 1 spontaneously creates a dipole, which induces dipoles in molecules 2 and 3. Thus, not only are dipoles 1 and 2 interacting, but dipoles 2 and 3 are also interacting. I will first show the derivation of the two-body interaction, and then present my conclusions on the three-body interactions.
The issue I am facing is that my conclusions don't match the literature. In the literature, this potential is referred to as the Axilrod-Teller potential, but it was derived from quantum perturbation theory. So my question is: are my assumptions incorrect, or is it that the classical approach cannot predict three-body interactions?
Derivation of 2-body London equation
$$d_2 \approx \alpha_2 E_{12}$$
The interaction between two dipoles is:
$$ w(r) = d_2E_{12} $$
So, in this case:
$$ w(r) = \alpha_2 E_{12}^2 $$
Knowing the electric field of a dipole at a point $r$ in space:
$$ E(r) = d\frac{(1+\cos^2\theta)^{1/2}}{(4\pi \epsilon_0 \epsilon) r^3} $$
We can then derive the interaction between the two particles. Israelachvili also states that we can average over the angle $ \theta $, because the two dipoles don't have time to align.
$$ w(r) \approx -\frac{ \alpha ^2 hv}{(4\pi\epsilon_0\epsilon)^2r^6}$$
The numerical details are not important for my question; this interaction correctly predicts the behavior of the interaction with respect to $r$.
Three-body contribution
The dipole of molecule 3 is:
$$d_3 \approx \alpha E_{13}\\
 w_{23}(r) = d_2E_{32} $$
Using the expression for the field created by a dipole:
$$ E_{32}(r) = d_3\frac{(1+\cos^2\theta_{32})^{1/2}}{(4\pi \epsilon_0 \epsilon) r_{32}^3} $$
Substituting $ d_3 $ with the field $ E_{13} $:
$$ E_{32}(r) = \alpha^2 hv \frac{(1+\cos^2\theta_{32})^{1/2}(1+\cos^2\theta_{13})^{1/2}}{(4\pi \epsilon_0 \epsilon)^2 r_{32}^3 r_{13}^3}   $$
Where now we must average over $ \theta_{32} $ and $ \theta_{13} $, numeric details don't care, the fact is that the expression for interaction is:
$$ w(r_{13},r_{32}) = \frac{\alpha^3 C}{r_{32}^3 r_{13}^3} $$
But the expresion Axilrod and Teller (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axilrod%E2%80%93Teller_potential) gets also deppends on $ r_{12} $:
$$ w(r_{13},r_{32}) = \frac{\alpha^3 C}{r_{32}^3 r_{13}^3 r_{12}^3} $$
I personally like my result better. Since if you make $ r_{12} $ exactly 0 you recover the solution of have 1 particle with the double of polarizability, since $r_{32} = r_{13}$.
Other option is that I am wrong and Axilrod and Teller is the next order correction and my solution is fine, if so, I have not found my solution anywhere so if someone find it it would be appreciated.

There is still a typo in the title. On PSE the names of physics Nobel laureates should always be spelled correctly. Only then can we proceed to the answer.
